# Why is an EventLoopGroup required for a client connected over a LocalChannel?

Tags: netty

This may actually pertain to client's in general, using `Bootstrap` -- clearly the group is required for any client.

But if you have multiple clients running on a single JVM, you really eat up a lot of memory creating an `EventLoopGroup` for each and can pretty easily OOM yourself.

I was able to work around this by having a global `EventLoopGroup` that is shared amongst all clients in the JVM and uses reference counting to make sure its cleanly inited and destroyed, but this seems more like a workaround than the intended design.

And there didn't seem to be any `EventLoopGroup` implementation that would just use a single-threaded executor, something that would execute the calls of the client serially; which I realize is somewhat at odds with Netty's async nature, but it's a legit use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EventLoopGroup` is intended to be shared between multiple client channels.  You don't need to create a new `EventLoopGroup` for each channel you create.

I'm not sure why you had to introduce reference counting for the life cycle of `EventLoopGroup`, but you could just shut it down when your application is about to terminate itself.  Alternatively, you can specify a `ThreadFactory` that creates a daemon thread, then JVM will terminate without waiting for the threads created by `EventLoopGroup`.  Netty actually provides `DefaultThreadFactory` which is convenient for creating a daemon thread.

To make `EventLoopGroup` single-threaded, just specify `1` as a constructor parameter.

Comment: I went with the reference counting approach because at first each client was creating its own EventLoopGroup, and load testing which was spawning many clients to hit a remote server, ate up a ton of memory, even when single threaded.  I could have injected a global event group into the clients and let it be re-used that way, but the ref counting was an easier approach.

Comment: Any suggestion for an improvement on the Netty side with respect to your use case?

Comment: If group was optional, that would have been fine.  For me, at least, the thread pool for the client is too heavyweight and i just needed a way around that when load testing.  Or if there was an easy way to specify some sort of callerRuns group, similar to ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy, that would have worked fine.  The clients were already in their own thread.  Lastly if there was an easy way to create a group that wraps an existing ExecutorService, which then I could have managed separately which would have been useful (granted that similar to what i do now)